# What is the meaning of the vernacular "beasted"?

Tags: slang, vernacular

Is anyone familiar with the vernacular term "beasted", used as a verb?

> e.g. I beasted my exam.

My colleague's teenaged son used this exact phrase in a text-message. And she had no idea whether this was a good or bad thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know Urban Dictionary is not usually a trusted source, but I think it is your friend here.

From number 2, [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beasted):

> To have excelled at something as if using super-human beast like skills.

I heard this phrase used frequently whilst at university, but not so much since leaving. So I guess it's either a term particular to the student crowd, or to that particular area of the country.

Comment: Also, well done to your colleague's son on his superb exam performance!

Comment: I suspect its got a similar origin to the military term beasting http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beasting

Answer (score 2):

It depends when it is used. When used on a performance, it means cool, super, excellent.

> **I beasted the exam!**

When used on a guy, it can mean cool, or tank.

> **That guy is beast**

However, when used on a girl, it means unattractive:

> **That girl is beast.**

http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-of/beasting-them

Comment: Ok thanks, but I now have a new question. "Tank"?

Comment: Slang for well-built

Answer (score 1):

I think he meant "bested".  Mysteriously, it means the same thing as "worsted"; to wit, "defeated".

Comment: Let me just ask my colleague....No, having spoken to her son, it seems he did mean to write "beasted".

Answer (score 1):

The term 'beasted' is very common in the British Army.  Often described as 'being ragged until your eyeballs bleed'.

ARRSE definition - http://www.arrse.co.uk/wiki/Beasting

In the context of having 'beasted an exam' - that would seem to me to be a good thing..