# When did beast become a verb?

Tags: grammar, slang, language-evolution, lexicon

In recent times, people have started using the word *beast* as a verb (i.e., *beast it*, *you've got to beast harder*).

Is there any information about when this trend started and how it came about?

Comment: [Verbing weirds language](http://www.strangehorizons.com/2006/20060313/verbing_weirds_language.gif)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26066/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-vernacular-beasted

Comment: this is a dup...

Comment: I disagree it's a duplicate. This question isn't asking about the meaning but the origin.

Answer (score 3):

It appears it is used mainly as military slang and in football.

[to beast](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beast) verb:

> beast (third-person singular simple present beasts, present participle beasting, simple past and past participle beasted)
>
> (UK, military) to impose arduous exercises, either as training or as punishment.

[to beast](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beast) — vb:

> military slang , slang chiefly  ( Brit ) ( tr ) to punish or torture (someone) in a manner that involves excessive physical exercise

[to beast it](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Beast%20It) (slang)

> To use brute strength and massive force to do something. Also, this action may be classified as going crazy on an object. Perons who do these actions are usually called "beasts" or "savages." Usually used in association with football players, originating from the "savage" players who hit hard.
>
> Person 1: Stupid stapler. It's not working. 
>   Football player: Just beast it. 
>   Person 1: Wow cool it works now.

The only evidence I can find in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beast%20it,%20beast%20hard&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,beast%20it;,c0;.t1;,beast%20hard;,c0) shows a very limited use of the expressions you mentioned. Hope other users can produce more evidence on this.

Answer (score 1):

The OED entry for *beast* as a verb was last updated in 1887, but both of the senses they list are related to the military slang meaning “punishment/forfeit through arduous exercise” (which isn't listed explicitly). The citations are surprisingly early.

OED insists on documentary evidence of how a word has been used, which can make slang difficult to date. Slang might be expected to be first **written** long after it entered the language in speech. *Beast* as military slang has definitely [appeared in print](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/onthefrontline/2158031/British-soldier-Gavin-Williams-died-of-heatstroke-in-beasting-punishment.html) recently, but probably hadn’t before 1887. A [Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beast_VERB&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) for `beast_VERB` finds nothing at all, even going back to 1600.

> †**1.** *trans.* To make a beast of, treat as a beast.
>
> > 1646   S. Bolton *Arraignm. of Errovr* 151   And having thus beasted men, they [Papists] say to them..‘You are..in no way able to judge of Questions of truth.’
>
> **2.** *pass.* In the game of Ombre: To fail to win the game (said of the Ombre), or to incur a forfeit for breaking the rules.
>
> > 1653   T. Urquhart tr. Rabelais *1st Bk. Wks.* v,   We will not be beasted at this bout, for I have got one trick.